# How to present 200k selectable records on a website

Tags: php

i have big problem on my site, i have this function to get all category from data base :-

```
public function selectallcatdata()
{
    $query = mysql_query("select Category_name,Category_id from category where Category_delete='0'");
    return $query;
    mysql_free_result($query);
}
```

and i use this function on select type like this :-

```
<select name="txtCompanyCat" id="txtCompanyCat">
<option selected value="">choose the Category ... </option>
<?php 
$CategoryNameData = $select -> selectallcatdata();
while($CatNameRow = mysql_fetch_array($CategoryNameData)){
    $CatID = $CatNameRow['Category_id'];
    $CatName = $CatNameRow['Category_name'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $CatID; ?>"><?php echo $CatName; ?></option>
<?php } 
unset($CatID);
unset($CatName);
?>
</select>
```

So, the problem is i have 251932 rows on this table and we must show all this rows from my table, how can i solve this load.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: there are 251932 categories which he will show in select box, can he reduce that load?

Comment: And what is the problem? how to load? I think that the problem isn't the retrieve of the row what he would like to view? what is the goal? @codefreak

Comment: when open my site this part not open, but open after 30 min

Comment: `251932` any user will stop and make use of category, instead use `ajax` as refined by @partoa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A select box with 251,932 items is hardly practical at all. I recommend you use an AJAX auto-complete for your front end which would permit you to fetch fewer results at a time.
There are a few of those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856305/autocomplete-form-from-database-php-mysql-ajax), [here](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) and many more. You can make a pick according to your requirements. [This one](https://github.com/partoa/FCBKcomplete) works with a regular select very well; I worked on it a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried benchmarking your site to find out where the delay comes from? I'm fairly sure that with that many records it's the query time as well as the rendering time. It's just too much data. Implementing some caching for the database queries could help on one end, but the database is not really the major problem here, I think.

You will have to avoid showing all categories. There is just no other way to deal with something like this. I can imagine two approaches that might work for you:

1. You try sorting the categories into several super-categories and the
   user first selects on of those super categories and then the
   categories that belong to it will be lazy-loaded (maybe via AJAX).
2. Instead of showing all catgories, you provide an input field that will show a list of
   suggested categories based on what the user types into the field.
3. It might be a good idea to try deriving a list of matching categories by analyzing all 
   other data the user entered. Considering the amount of available values it really might 
   be worth investing the time to build a text mining approach to deal with that.

The most obvious would be to reduce the number of categories, but I guess that's out of the question.

Oh, and on a side note: `return` prematurely ends the function execution, so your `mysql_free_result($query);` will never be reached. It's the wrong place to put it anyway. You should free the result, once you're done processing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if it is a static query, you can cache the result instead of fetching it every time. It will definitely be load first time but for later request it won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

change select box  to search box , then ajax call php .